# forcing my property to accept only certain kinds of data types

Tags: c#-4.0

```
 public object Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {

            _value = value;
        }
    }

   public enum someEnum
      {
         sString = 1,
         sBoolean = 2,
         sInt     = 3,
         sDate    = 4
         sData    = 5  //Custom data type eg; a class
      }
```

I want my property value to accept and return only the datatypes specified in the someEnum   enumerator. I am using vs2012

Comment: After looking at this - may I ask: Why do you need this?

Comment: I need my property to accept only certain kinds of data types that we have laid out in the enumerator.

Comment: ok - but it looks like you may be moving in the "diffecult" direction. Anyways - have you seen my suggested solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with enum, it works but I had to hard code enum values like "System.String" and used Enum.TryParse in set modifier.

```
MyEnum type;
bool res = Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>(Convert.ToString(value.GetType()), out type);
```

IMHO, it looks better with extension methods

```
private object _value;
public object Value
{
    get
    {
        return _value;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value.IsValidType())
            _value = value;
        else
            throw new Exception("Not a valid type");
    }
}

public static class ObjectExtenstions
{
    public static bool IsValidType(this object obj)
    {
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(System.String) || obj.GetType() == typeof(System.Int32))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
public someEnum Value
{
 get; set;
}
```